# How can I copy Storyblok space to another account?

Tags: storyblok

I faced with the issue of copying entire space from Storyblok (from one account to another)
I can't find another way except

```
storyblok push-components <SOURCE> --space <SPACE_ID> --presets-source <PRESETS_SOURCE>
```

But this method doesn't includes assets and internationalization, and schemas.
Also find this way [export as csv](https://github.com/storyblok/example-scripts/tree/master/import-export-csv), but it doesn't include internationalization

Is there any way to copy entire space and put it on another account?

Comment: you can do like this way https://www.storyblok.com/faq/how-to-transfer-the-ownership-of-a-space

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to sync components, folder, roles, datasources or stories between spaces, but not accounts.

`$ storyblok sync --type <COMMAND> --source <SPACE_ID> --target <SPACE_ID>`

type: describe the command type to execute. Can be: folders, components, stories, datasources or roles. It's possible pass multiple types separated by comma (,).

If you want to move everything in the account contact their support team